# Programmatically add PrimeNG elements to DOM

Tags: angular, primeng

Dears,
Like in JQuery we use #div.append('') or #div.append('......'),
is it possible to add PrimeNG elements like input text, input numbers, dropdown, multi selects programmatically using some apis with json format or whatever ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you've added angular as a tag..

just use *ngFor in your html, then for every Json object you place in the array you can generate any elements you want, example:

```
items: MyItem[];
```

```
<app-custom-component *ngFor="let item of items" [myItem]="item"></app-custom-component>
```

the customComponent handles it like this:

```
@Input() myItem: MyItem;
```

```
<h1>{{myItem.title}}</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="myItem.description" />
```

ect...

Or a very basic example:

```
items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

```
<h2 *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</h2>
```